# How to calculate

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Item     Qty    Price A         Price B
abc       5      36.00                0
qwe       8          0            48.00
zxc       6      12.00                0
poi       4      10.00                0
lkj       9      12.00                0
mnb       3          0            14.00     
vfr       7          0             6.00
```

How can I sum the value using SQL ie. if Price A is zero, it will pick Price B. The expected results will be as follows :-

```
Item       Value
abc        180.00
qwe        384.00
zxc         72.00
poi         40.00
lkj         36.00
mnb         42.00
vfr         42.00
```

Comment: Please edit and use the code-formatting feature/button, to make the example data readable.

Comment: lkj 9 x 12 = 108 not 36?

Comment: So what is supposed to happen if both values are non-zero?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
 ITEM
 , (Qty * [Price A]) + (Qty * [Price B]) AS Value
FROM
 TableName
```

Comment: What if price A and B are non-zero?

Comment: Clever :-) It is worth stating explicitly the underlying assumption, that one of the prices is (should be) always 0.

Comment: True, in the example (requirements) Bob delivered they are always 0

Comment: It will be either A or B but not A & B ie.A & B are non-zero or A & B with values.

Comment: What happens when A & B both have value?

Comment: Can you label this answer as the solution

Answer (score 2):

Use the following if A and B could be non-zero, and you only want to use price A when this occurs:

```
SELECT Item, CASE WHEN `Price A` != 0 THEN `Price A` * Qty
                  ELSE `Price B` * Qty
             END AS Value
FROM table;
```

Comment: +1 This always gives the expected result (even if both prices are nonzero).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like

```
SELECT SUM(Price A) FROM table; SELECT SUM(Price B) FROM table WHERE Price A = 0;
```

And then add the results together...

Answer (score 0):

from the example above you could really just select priceA + priceB, since one or the other is always zero, otherwise... I am not quite sure this can be done in pure SQL...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both can be not null:

`SELECT item, QTY * IF(PriceA!=0, PriceA, PriceB) AS VALUE from tableName;`